# Project error with FBSDKCoreKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, cocoapods

I update cocoa pods to 0.38.1, and now i have problem with FBSDKCoreKit.
When app starting it's stop on starting screen with error:

```
    dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/F88E950B-DE6A-4886-8491-BAA4F4477CE0/Yoop.app/Yoop
  Reason: Incompatible library version: Yapper requires version 4.0.0 or later, but FBSDKCoreKit provides version 1.0.0
```

Who know how to fix it?

Comment: Check that framework is embedded in the iOS app bundle.

Comment: @trojanfoe not working

Comment: @trojanfoe [link](http://s21.postimg.org/ec8sq8w93/Screen_Shot_2015_07_24_at_16_11_34.png)

Comment: Check that framework is embedded in the iOS app bundle.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the same issue and neither adding pods nor the fbsdk libs to embedded binaries did help.

Comment: any luck with this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try deleting your DerivedData Folder. Solved it for me.

Comment: I haven't seen this issue since then. I was at least able to get back to running my app.

Comment: wacking = Delete?

Comment: Do not update the iPhone for new firmware. SWIFT 4 - SWIFT 5
I have updated iPhone7 for iOS 13.3.1 and tried to clean DerivedData, every framework... Only other device with a lower iOS version will help sometimes. 
The simulator could be useful too.

Answer (score 16):

For me the solution was to add AND embed the framework under project -> General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content:

[image: screenshot embedded content]

Answer (score 5):

In your Xcode ,go the `General` tab of your Main Project.. there you will find an `Embedded Binaries` field and add the required framework there . Crash will be resolved.

Comment: Multiple commands produce '/Users/akademobi5/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-bvamfyjzwdmbhwcjobymztngebbc/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/test.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework':
1) Target 'test' has copy command from '/Users/akademobi5/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fixCam-bvamfyjzwdmbhwcjobymztngebbc/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit.framework' to '/Users/akademobi5/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-bvamfyjzwdmbhwcjobymztngebbc/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/test.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework'

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding FBSDKCoreKit.xcframework and FBSDKGamingServiceKit.xcframewrok in Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content like in the image bellow.

[FBSDKCoreKit.xcframework and FBSDKGamingServiceKit.xcframewrok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOlJr.png)