# Library not loaded: @rpath/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, facebook-login, react-native-fbsdk

i am trying to add library `react-native-fbsdk-next` to my react native app to make a log in with facebook button. I followed install instruction of facebook to set up Facebook SDK for iOS. The app successfully built, however, I got this error:
dyld[54430]: Library not loaded:

```
@rpath/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit
  Referenced from: /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0556C9E-4F68-4C77-9C53-17AC58D85278/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/97EBA641-370F-4795-8218-83D7D7F9F778/eCommercialApp.app/Frameworks/react_native_fbsdk_next.framework/react_native_fbsdk_next
  Reason: tried: '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eCommercialApp-dehghjkotvmxkidrbfdhdrffgutk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'arm64,x86_64', need 'x86_64')), '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eCommercialApp-dehghjkotvmxkidrbfdhdrffgutk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PackageFrameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (no such file), '/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0556C9E-4F68-4C77-9C53-17AC58D85278/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/97EBA641-370F-4795-8218-83D7D7F9F778/eCommercialApp.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'arm64,x86_64', need 'x86_64')), '/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0556C9E-4F68-4C77-9C53-17AC58D85278/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/97EBA641-370F-4795-8218-83D7D7F9F778/eCommercialApp.app/Frameworks/react_native_fbsdk_next.framework/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (no such file), '/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0556C9E-4F68-4C77-9C53-17AC58D85278/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/97EBA641-370F-4795-8218-83D7D7F9F778/eCommercialApp.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'arm64,x86_64', need 'x86_64')), '/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0556C9E-4F68-4C77-9C53-17AC58D85278/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/97EBA641-370F-4795-8218-83D7D7F9F778/eCommercialApp.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'arm64,x86_64', need 'x86_64')), '/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0556C9E-4F68-4C77-9C53-17AC58D85278/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/97EBA641-370F-4795-8218-83D7D7F9F778/eCommercialApp.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'arm64,x86_64', need 'x86_64')), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (no such file), '/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0556C9E-4F68-4C77-9C53-17AC58D85278/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/97EBA641-370F-4795-8218-83D7D7F9F778/eCommercialApp.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'arm64,x86_64', need 'x86_64')), '/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0556C9E-4F68-4C77-9C53-17AC58D85278/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/97EBA641-370F-4795-8218-83D7D7F9F778/eCommercialApp.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'arm64,x86_64', need 'x86_64')), '/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0556C9E-4F68-4C77-9C53-17AC58D85278/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/97EBA641-370F-4795-8218-83D7D7F9F778/eCommercialApp.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'arm64,x86_64', need 'x86_64')), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (no such file)
Library not loaded: @rpath/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit
  Referenced from: /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0556C9E-4F68-4C77-9C53-17AC58D85278/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/97EBA641-370F-4795-8218-83D7D7F9F778/eCommercialApp.app/Frameworks/react_native_fbsdk_next.framework/react_native_fbsdk_next
  Reason: tried: '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eCommercialApp-dehghjkotvmxkidrbfdhdrffgutk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'arm64,x86_64', need 'x86_64')), '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eCommercialApp-dehghjkotvmxkidrbfdhdrffgutk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PackageFrameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' (no such file), '/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0556C9E-4F68-4C77-9C53-17AC58D85278/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/97EBA641-370F-47
(lldb)
```

I have spent two days to fix this issue but nothing happened. So everyone have an answer please help me. I am appreciated for your response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61633482/19475365) helped me.

In your project select General and Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content. Click plus icon and manually add FBSDKCoreKit with .xcframework extension. Check the Xcode console for errors, add more frameworks if needed.

Refer to my settings on the screenshot below.

Hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.You can refer [Facebook-ios-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/2121)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).